# Mockito testcases for pojo classes

Tags: java, mockito

I have pojo  class in my project:

```
class ABC {

    private String status;
    private int rate;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status=status
    } 
}

@Test public retur_status { abc.setStatus("data"); abc.getStatus();}
```

I have written a test case for the above method, but shows no coverage for that method. How to write Mockito test case for setter and getter methods?

Comment: You don't need Mockito to test a POJO. Mockito is to stub any dependencies (e.g. database call) which a POJO won't have. Show us your current JUnit code.

Answer (score 4):

You **only** require mocking when you have to *control/manipulate* the behavior of objects that are **used** by your code under test.

In that sense: no need at all for mocks when working on true POJO objects. Instead, a typical test could look like:

```
@Test
public void testConstructorAndGetter() {
  PojoUnderTest underTest = new PojoUnderTest("some name");
  assertThat(underTest.getName(), is("some name"));
}
```

... similar for pairs of setter/getter methods.

Please note: I am using the JUnit *assertThat* assert; as it is simply the most powerful and useful assert ... the thing to know here: you need Hamcrest matchers (such as *is*) for it. But once you got used to that, you will not use anything else.